# GO problem with positioning in fyne.io - Move method doesn't work

Tags: go, fyne

I am making a simple application with fyne, but I have a problem with text placement.

As you can see from the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARp8W.png), I managed to position the form components with an edge from the window, but I can't do the same with the underlying components (the Move method doesn't work).

Here the main file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "weather-app/ui"
    "weather-app/utils"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
)

func main() {
    prova, err := utils.MakeRequest("palermo", "it")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(prova.Weather[0])
        fmt.Println(prova.Main)
        fmt.Println(prova.Sys)
        fmt.Println(prova.Dt)
    }

    app := app.New()
    window := app.NewWindow("Current Weather")

    customForm := ui.GenerateCustomForm()
    apiResults := ui.ShowApiResults("Cinisi", "20 °C")

    wrapper := container.NewGridWithRows(
        2,
        customForm,
        apiResults,
    )

    window.Resize(fyne.NewSize(445, 400))
    window.SetContent(wrapper)

    window.ShowAndRun()
}
```

The ui:

```
package ui

import (
    "fmt"
    "image/color"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func onSubmitFunc(city, country string) {
    fmt.Println("submit")
}

func GenerateCustomForm() *fyne.Container {
    //creating widgets
    cityEntry := widget.NewEntry()
    countrEntry := widget.NewEntry()
    button := widget.NewButton("Search", func() { onSubmitFunc(cityEntry.Text, countrEntry.Text) })

    //set placeholder in text input
    cityEntry.SetPlaceHolder("City")
    countrEntry.SetPlaceHolder("Country (optional)")

    //setting size
    cityEntry.Resize(fyne.NewSize(250, 40))
    countrEntry.Resize(fyne.NewSize(150, 40))
    button.Resize(fyne.NewSize(160, 40))

    //positioning
    cityEntry.Move(fyne.NewPos(10, 10))
    countrEntry.Move(fyne.NewPos(cityEntry.Size().Width+25, 10))
    button.Move(fyne.NewPos(10, 25))

    customForm := container.New(
        layout.NewVBoxLayout(),
        container.NewWithoutLayout(
            cityEntry,
            countrEntry,
        ),
        container.NewWithoutLayout(
            button,
        ),
    )

    return customForm
}

func ShowApiResults(city, temp string) *fyne.Container {
    text := canvas.NewText("Current weather in "+city, color.White)
    text.TextSize = 18

    temperature := canvas.NewText(temp, color.White)
    temperature.TextSize = 50

    //sample image
    r, _ := fyne.LoadResourceFromURLString("http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/09d@2x.png")
    image := canvas.NewImageFromResource(r)
    image.FillMode = canvas.ImageFillContain
    image.Resize(fyne.NewSize(100, 100))

    //wrap the components to have them on the same line
    tempAndImg := container.New(
        layout.NewGridLayout(2),
        temperature,
        image,
    )

    tempAndImg.Move(fyne.NewPos(20, 0)) //DOESN'T WORK

    apiResults := container.New(
        layout.NewVBoxLayout(),
        text,
        tempAndImg,
    )

    //i tried also this:
    //apiResults.Move(fyne.NewPos(20, 0)) --- but nothing

    return apiResults
}
```

I am still in the basics of fyne, I thank in advance anyone who can help me out.

Comment: How is this related to PHP, JS and Python? Don't tag-spam your question to expect more people helping. It will most likely just have the opposite effect.

Comment: related? [Fyne Golang: Resize/Move doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72897901/10197418)